# Some parts of css renders later after adding flex

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, gatsby, styled-jsx

I am developing a blog and I recently added a `div` element with `display: flex;` to make the elements appear in the same row.

However, after making this change whenever I load the page, the elements shift a bit to the right and the font loads up a bit late. This happens only for a while, after page loads they all shift back to their expected place.

note: This doesn't show up on my localhost, but only in the production build (or when deployed)

Please check the video below to see for yourselves:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3wNe.jpg

Or if on desktop witness it yourself: https://lucid-brown-a29dc1.netlify.app/

JSX

```
<li>
        <Link to={slug} key={slug} className="link">
            
          <h1 className="title">
            {title}
          </h1>
          
          <p className="meta">
            <span>
              <FaCalendar size={18} /> {prefix}
              </span>
            
            <div className="tags">
              {tags && tags.map(tag =>
                <Link to={`/tag/${tag.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}`}>
                  <span key={tag}> <FaTag size={18} /> {tag} </span>
                </Link>
              )}
            </div>
          </p>
          
          <p> {excerpt}</p>
        </Link>
</li>
```

The corresponding css:

```css
<style jsx>{`
        :global(.link) {
          width: 100%;
          color: ${theme.text.color.primary};
        }
        li {
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          // border-radius: ${theme.size.radius.default};
          margin: ${theme.space.l} 0 ${`calc(${theme.space.l} * 3)`};
          padding: ${theme.space.inset.s};
          position: relative;
          transition: all ${theme.time.duration.default};
          background: transparent;
          
          &::after {
            // border-top: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
            content: "";
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.5)`};
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all ${theme.time.duration.default};
            width: 50%;
          }
          &:first-child {
            margin-top: 10px;   
          }
          &:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
          }
        }
        .title {
          padding: ${theme.space.m} ${theme.space.s} 0;
          line-height: ${theme.blog.h1.lineHeight};
          font-size: ${theme.blog.h1.size};
          text-remove-gap: both;
          :global(.arrow) {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            top: 7px;
          }
        }
        .meta {
          // display: block;
          font-size: 0.8em;
          padding: ${theme.space.s} ${theme.space.s};
          margin: ${theme.space.m} 0;
          background: transparent;
          .tags {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            // flex-shrink: 0;
          }
          :global(svg) {
            // fill: ${theme.icon.color};
            fill: ${theme.text.color.primary};
            opacity: 0.5;
            margin: ${theme.space.inline.xs};
            position: relative;
            bottom: -0.4em;
          }
          span {
            // align-items: baseline;
            // display: flex;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: ${theme.space.xs} ${theme.space.s} ${theme.space.xs} 0;
            font-size: 0.8em;
          }
        }
        p {
          line-height: 1.5;
          padding: 0 ${theme.space.s};
          text-remove-gap: both;
        }
        @from-width tablet {
          li {
            margin: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 3)`} 0 ${theme.space.xl};
            padding: ${theme.space.default};
            &::after {
              bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2)`};
            }
            &:first-child {
              &::before {
                top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.75)`};
              }
            }
          }
          .title {
            font-size: ${`calc(${theme.blog.h1.size} * 1.2)`};
            padding: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 1.5) ${theme.space.default} 0`};
            transition: all 0.5s;
          }
          .meta {
            
            padding: ${theme.space.default} ${theme.space.default};
          }
          p {
            padding: 0 ${theme.space.default};
          }
        }
        @below desktop {
          li {
            border: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            
            &:first-child {
              margin-top: 0;
            }
            &::after {
              border-top: 0px;
            }
          }
        }
        @from-width desktop {
          li {
          
            margin: 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 ${theme.space.l};
            &::after {
              bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.5)`};
            }
            &:first-child {
              &::before {
                top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.75)`};
              }
            }
          }
          :global(.blogItemLink:first-child) > li::before {
            top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.75)`};
          }
          .title {
            font-size: 2.5em;
            padding: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 1.2)`} ${theme.space.l} 0;
          }
          .meta {
          
              padding: 0 ${theme.space.l} 0;
          }
          p {
            padding: 0 ${theme.space.l} 0;
          }
          li {
            &:hover {
              border: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
              box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
              &:after {
                bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.5)`};
              }
              :global(.gatsby-image-wrapper) {
                transform: scale(1.1);
              }
              .title {
                color: ${theme.blog.h1.hoverColor};
              }
          
            }
          
          }
        }
        @media (hover: hover) {
          .meta {
            :global(a svg) {
              transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            }
            :global(a:hover svg) {
              transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
              transform: scale(1.3);
              color: ${theme.color.brand.primary};
            }
          }
        }
      `}</style>
```

So far I have tried:

- changing `div` to `span` but that aligns the tags with the prefix above
- removing the `flex` but then how else do I align items in a row?
- trying to increase the css performance by removing complex calcs
- read that `grid` should be used instead of `flex` but looks like `grid` is not available (need to use some css framework perhaps?)
- I also observed that font color loads a bit later than the page, so may be this is not related to `flex` at all and I am simply barking up the wrong tree?

I am a css newbie so I may not be using the best practices here. Pasting the entire css here as I am not able to locate the cause of the issue. Is it because flex box is performance heavy? How can I mitigate this?

In case anyone wants to read the entire code: https://github.com/amita-shukla/blog-1/blob/master/src/components/Blog/Teaser.js

Answer (score 2):

The FOUC (**F**lash **O**F **U**nstyled **C**omponent) comes from multiple sources. In your case, I guess that loading CSS in as JSX component `<style jsx>` is blocking the rendering of the styles until they are parsed by the browser. Keep in mind that [JavaScript is a render-blocking](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS). In addition, the final behavior of your code should be tested in a `gatsby build` environment.

Before the browser can render a page it has to build the DOM tree by parsing the HTML markup. During this process, whenever the parser encounters a script it has to stop and execute it before it can continue parsing the HTML.

Try adding the styles as [Gatsby docs suggest](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/styling/):

- [Global CSS Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/): the traditional way to style a website. CSS rules are declared globally and styles are applied depending on specificity and inheritance.
- [Modular Stylesheets](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/css-modules): CSS rules are written traditionally but consumed with JavaScript and scoped locally to avoid unintended side-effects elsewhere. Works out-of-the-box with Gatsby.
- [CSS-in-JS](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/css-in-js/): locally-scoped CSS written and consumed in JavaScript, enabling the easier use of dynamic styling and other features. Requires the use of third-party libraries.

As an initial approach, I would suggest using CSS files:

```
import './styles.css'
// other imports


<li>
        <Link to={slug} key={slug} className="link">
            
          <h1 className="title">
            {title}
          </h1>
          
          <p className="meta">
            <span>
              <FaCalendar size={18} /> {prefix}
              </span>
            
            <div className="tags">
              {tags && tags.map(tag =>
                <Link to={`/tag/${tag.split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase()}`}>
                  <span key={tag}> <FaTag size={18} /> {tag} </span>
                </Link>
              )}
            </div>
          </p>
          
          <p> {excerpt}</p>
        </Link>
</li>
```

Assuming that styles.css is in the same folder than your React component. There, in your `styles.css`:

```
:global(.link) {
  width: 100%;
  color: ${theme.text.color.primary};
}
li {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  // border-radius: ${theme.size.radius.default};
  margin: ${theme.space.l} 0 ${`calc(${theme.space.l} * 3)`};
  padding: ${theme.space.inset.s};
  position: relative;
  transition: all ${theme.time.duration.default};
  background: transparent;
  
  &::after {
    // border-top: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.5)`};
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all ${theme.time.duration.default};
    width: 50%;
  }
  &:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;   
  }
  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
.title {
  padding: ${theme.space.m} ${theme.space.s} 0;
  line-height: ${theme.blog.h1.lineHeight};
  font-size: ${theme.blog.h1.size};
  text-remove-gap: both;
  :global(.arrow) {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
  }
}
.meta {
  // display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: ${theme.space.s} ${theme.space.s};
  margin: ${theme.space.m} 0;
  background: transparent;
  .tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    // flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  :global(svg) {
    // fill: ${theme.icon.color};
    fill: ${theme.text.color.primary};
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: ${theme.space.inline.xs};
    position: relative;
    bottom: -0.4em;
  }
  span {
    // align-items: baseline;
    // display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: ${theme.space.xs} ${theme.space.s} ${theme.space.xs} 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 ${theme.space.s};
  text-remove-gap: both;
}
@from-width tablet {
  li {
    margin: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 3)`} 0 ${theme.space.xl};
    padding: ${theme.space.default};
    &::after {
      bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2)`};
    }
    &:first-child {
      &::before {
        top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.75)`};
      }
    }
  }
  .title {
    font-size: ${`calc(${theme.blog.h1.size} * 1.2)`};
    padding: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 1.5) ${theme.space.default} 0`};
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  .meta {
    
    padding: ${theme.space.default} ${theme.space.default};
  }
  p {
    padding: 0 ${theme.space.default};
  }
}
@below desktop {
  li {
    border: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    &:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    &::after {
      border-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}
@from-width desktop {
  li {
  
    margin: 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 ${theme.space.l};
    &::after {
      bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -1.5)`};
    }
    &:first-child {
      &::before {
        top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.75)`};
      }
    }
  }
  :global(.blogItemLink:first-child) > li::before {
    top: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.75)`};
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * 1.2)`} ${theme.space.l} 0;
  }
  .meta {
  
      padding: 0 ${theme.space.l} 0;
  }
  p {
    padding: 0 ${theme.space.l} 0;
  }
  li {
    &:hover {
      border: 1px solid ${theme.line.color};
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
      &:after {
        bottom: ${`calc(${theme.space.default} * -2.5)`};
      }
      :global(.gatsby-image-wrapper) {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      .title {
        color: ${theme.blog.h1.hoverColor};
      }
  
    }
  
  }
}
@media (hover: hover) {
  .meta {
    :global(a svg) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    :global(a:hover svg) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
      transform: scale(1.3);
      color: ${theme.color.brand.primary};
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: of course changing the variables for CSS-based ones. Alternatively, use styled-components.*

Keep also in mind that if you want to add [global styles](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-global-styles/), the easiest and native approach is using the `gatsby-browser.js` file:

```
import "./src/styles/global.css"

// or:
// require('./src/styles/global.css')
```